# Why EAGAIN in pthread_key_create happens?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Sometimes when I try to create key with `pthread_key_create` I'm getting EAGAIN error code. Is it possible to know exactly why?

Documentation says:

> The system lacked the necessary resources to create another thread-specific data key, or the system-imposed limit on the total number of keys per process [PTHREAD_KEYS_MAX] would be exceeded.

How to check if it was a limit for keys? Maybe some king of monitor tool to check how many keys already opened in system and how many still could be used?

One important thing about our code: we use `fork()` and have multiple processes running. And each process could have multiple threads.

I found that we don't have independent limit for thread keys when we use `fork()`. Here is little example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

size_t create_keys(pthread_key_t *keys, size_t number_of_keys)
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_keys; i++)
    {
        int e = pthread_key_create(keys + i, NULL);
        if (e)
        {
            printf("ERROR (%d): index: %ld, pthread_key_create (%d)\n", getpid(), i, e);
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("maximim number of thread keys: %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_THREAD_KEYS_MAX));

    printf("process id: %d\n", getpid());

    const size_t number_of_keys = 1024;

    pthread_key_t keys_1[number_of_keys];
    memset(keys_1, 0, number_of_keys * sizeof(pthread_key_t));

    printf("INFO (%d): number of active keys: %ld\n", getpid(), create_keys(keys_1, number_of_keys));

    pid_t p = fork();
    if (p == 0)
    {
        printf("process id: %d\n", getpid());

        pthread_key_t keys_2[number_of_keys];
        memset(keys_2, 0, number_of_keys * sizeof(pthread_key_t));

        printf("INFO (%d): number of active keys: %ld\n", getpid(), create_keys(keys_2, number_of_keys));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this example on Ubuntu 16.04 I see that child process can not create any new thread key if I use same number of keys as limit (1024). But if I use 512 keys for parent and child processes I can run it without error.

Comment: Assuming you meant `PTHREAD_KEYS_MAX`, it's defined in `<limits.h>`. You can easily track how many times you call `pthread_key_create()` by incrementing an atomic int each time, and then compare the two values after getting that error. It's 1024 on my system, though. Why are you creating that many different thread local variables? Doesn't seem right. Show your code; I bet you're doing something wrong with how you're trying to use them.

Comment: @Shawn yes, we create many processes (Apache + fork) and each process could have many threads. So using atomic counter is not a good idea, because I need to have such counter across all processes.

Comment: Huh? Number of processes doesn't matter; each one has its own set of keys. Number of threads in a process doesn't matter either; it's the number of thread local storage keys a particular process has that does matters. There's definitely something you're not understanding about the concept of thread-specific data. Show a [MCVE].

Comment: @Shawn I created little example for `fork()` and it looks like number of processes is matter.

Comment: Your child process can't create any more keys when using 1024 because the parent already created the maximum number before forking...

Answer (score 1):

As you know, fork() traditionally works by copying the process in memory and then continuing execution from the same point within each copy as parent and child. This is what the return code of fork() indicates.

In order to perform fork(), the internals of the process must be duplicated. Memory, stack, open files, and probably thread local storage keys. Each system is different in its implementation of fork(). Some systems allow you to customise the areas of the process that get copied (see Linux clone(2) interface). However, the concept remains the same.

So, on to your example code: if you allocate 1024 keys in the parent, every child process inherits a full key table and has no spare keys to work with, resulting in the errors. If you allocate only 512 keys in the parent, then every child inherits a half-empty keys table and has 512 spare keys to play with, hence no errors arise.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum value:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  printf ("%ld\n", sysconf(_SC_THREAD_KEYS_MAX));
  return 0;
}
```

Consider using [`pthread_key_delete`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_delete).